# I am building a Basic Stat Header File in C and having problems

Tags: c, struct, header, statistics

This is my first post, so I apologize if the syntax is incorrect. What I am trying to do is build a basic Header File to do some statistical analysis. I would rather write my own code in C than us programs like R or SPSS. It has been a few years, and I am a bit rusty.

NOTE: I am a fairly novice programmer and I rely on many tools shown to me in college. For example, in school my professor wrote a compiler and header file called `FPT.h`. I am not positive what is in there, I think it is mostly graphics, but I add it to all my code anyway. I do not think I use it in the following code, so you should be able to comment it out without a problem. I also use his compiler, acom, which I will add to the bottom of the question.

Here is the Header File, called `rd_stat.h`:

```
#ifndef mdr_stat_stuff
#define mdr_stat_stuff 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <FPT.h>

typedef struct {
  double mean;
  double median;
  double mode;
  double stddev;
  double q1;
  double q3;
  double low;
  double hi;
} 
BSTAT;

void  sort_doubles  (double data[], int size);
double get_mean     (double data[], int size);
double get_median   (double data[], int size);
double get_q1 (double data[], int size);
double get_q3 (double data[], int size);
int    get_mode     (double data[], int size);
double get_stddev   (double data[], int size);

struct BSTAT init_bstat(double data[], int size);

#endif
```

Here is its compiler friend rd_stat.c:

```
#ifndef mdr_stat_stuff
#define mdr_stat_stuff 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <FPT.h>
#include <rd_stat.h>

void sort_doubles(double data[],int size){
  int i, j;
  double temp;

  //Sorts the data in Ascending Order  
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < (size - i - 1); j++){
      if (data[j] > data[j + 1]){
    temp = data[j];
    data[j] = data[j + 1];
    data[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

double get_mean(double data[], int size){//to get the mean we need the array and its length
  int i;
  double mean = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    mean += data[i];
  }
  return mean / size;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


double get_median(double data[], int size){
  //only returns one median even if SIZE is even
  //if SIZE is even, it finds both medians and takes the average of the two
  //DECISION because it is often done anyway when there are two Medians. Seems more practical. 
  int i, j;
  double temp;

  sort_doubles(data, size);

  /* if(size % 2 == 0){//even cases */
  /*   return (data[size / 2 - 1] + data[size / 2]) / 2; */
  /* }else{//odd cases */
  /*   return data[(size - 1) / 2]; */
  /* }  */

  printf("location for median is  %5.2lf\n", ((double)size-1) / 2);


  return (data[(int)floor(((double)size-1) / 2)] + data[(int)ceil(((double)size-1) / 2)]) / 2;
}

double get_q1(double data[], int size){
  int i, j;
  double temp;

  sort_doubles(data, size);

  printf("location for q1 is  %5.2lf\n", (double)size / 4);

  return (data[(int)floor((double)size / 4)] + data[(int)ceil((double)size / 4)]) / 2;
}

double get_q3(double data[], int size){
  int i, j;
  double temp;

  sort_doubles(data, size);

  printf("location for q3 is  %5.2lf\n", (double)(3*size-4) / 4);

  return (data[(int)floor((3*(double)size-4) / 4)] + data[(int)ceil((3*(double)size-4) / 4)]) / 2;
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int get_mode(double data[],int size) {
  //Code augmented from other user:
  //https://www.tutorialspoint.com/learn_c_by_examples/mode_program_in_c.htm


  //Function assumes there is EXCATLY ONE Mode in the data. 
  //I don't like this

  int maxValue = 0, maxCount = 0, i, j;

   sort_doubles(data, size);

  //Finds Mode
   for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      int count = 0;      
      for (j = 0; j < size ; ++j) {
         if (data[j] == data[i])
         ++count;
      }      
      if (count > maxCount) {
         maxCount = count;
         maxValue = data[i];
      }      
   } 
     return maxValue;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
double get_stddev(double data[], int size){

  double mean = get_mean(data, size);
  int i;
  double sum=0;

  for(i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){
    sum += pow(data[i] - mean, 2);
  }
  return sqrt(sum / size);
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


BSTAT init_bstat(double data[], int size){

  BSTAT a;
  a.mean = get_mean(data, size);
  a.q1 = get_q1(data, size);
  a.median = get_median(data, size);
  a.q3 = get_q3(data, size);
  a.mode = get_mode(data, size);
  a.stddev = get_stddev(data, size);

  sort_doubles(data, size);
  a.low = data[0];
  a.hi = data[size - 1];


  return a;

}


#endif
```

And here is the program I am trying to kick start, test_bstat.c: 
*NOTE: before I put the function init_bstat() in the header file and its compiler, I wrote is in test_bstat.c to make sure it worked. Once I got it all squared away I copied it into rd_stat.c and added its declaration to the rd_stat.h. That is when the problems began.

```
#include <FPT.h>
#include <rd_stat.h>



/* BSTAT init_bstat(double data[], int size){ */

/*   BSTAT a; */
/*   a.mean = get_mean(data, size);        */
/*   a.median = get_median(data, size); */
/*   a.mode = get_mode(data, size); */
/*   a.stddev = get_stddev(data, size); */

/*   sort_doubles(data, size); */
/*   a.low = data[0]; */
/*   a.hi = data[size - 1]; */
/*   a.q1 = get_q1(data, size); */
/*   a.q3 = get_q3(data, size); */

/*   return a; */
/* } */



int main(){

  int size = 10;
  int i = 0;
  double scores[10];

  for(i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){
    scores[i] = floor(15*drand48() + 80);
  }

  for(i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){
    printf("Scores[%d] = %.2lf\n", i, scores[i]);
  }


  BSTAT LEANN;

 LEANN = init_bstat(scores, size);

  printf("Mean = %5.1lf Median = %5.1lf Mode = %5.0lf\n", LEANN.mean, LEANN.median, LEANN.mode);
  printf("Low = %5.1lf Hi = %5.1lf Stddev = %5.1lf Q1 = %5.1lf Q3 = %5.1lf\n", LEANN.low, LEANN.hi, LEANN.stddev, LEANN.q1, LEANN.q3);

}
```

The way I am compiling this is all through my professor's compiler, acom:

```
acom test_bstat.c rd_stat.c -I. rd_stat.h
```

When I compile, these are the following errors I receive:

```
user@OptiPlex-780:~/CS/FOOTBALL$ acom test_bstat.c rd_stat.c -I. rd_stat.h
test_bstat.c: In function ‘main’:
test_bstat.c:44:2: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct BSTAT’
  LEANN = init_bstat(scores, size);
  ^
rd_stat.c:126:1: error: unknown type name ‘BSTAT’
 BSTAT init_bstat(double data[], int size){
 ^
rd_stat.c: In function ‘init_bstat’:
rd_stat.c:128:3: error: unknown type name ‘BSTAT’
   BSTAT a;
   ^
rd_stat.c:129:4: error: request for member ‘mean’ in something not a structure or union
   a.mean = get_mean(data, size);
    ^
rd_stat.c:130:4: error: request for member ‘q1’ in something not a structure or union
   a.q1 = get_q1(data, size);
    ^
rd_stat.c:131:4: error: request for member ‘median’ in something not a structure or union
   a.median = get_median(data, size);
    ^
rd_stat.c:132:4: error: request for member ‘q3’ in something not a structure or union
   a.q3 = get_q3(data, size);
    ^
rd_stat.c:133:4: error: request for member ‘mode’ in something not a structure or union
   a.mode = get_mode(data, size);
    ^
rd_stat.c:134:4: error: request for member ‘stddev’ in something not a structure or union
   a.stddev = get_stddev(data, size);
    ^
rd_stat.c:137:4: error: request for member ‘low’ in something not a structure or union
   a.low = data[0];
    ^
rd_stat.c:138:4: error: request for member ‘hi’ in something not a structure or union
   a.hi = data[size - 1];
    ^
```

It seems like it is not recognizing the struct BSTAT as a valid return type and I am not sure why. Any clue as to why this could be the case?

Also, if anyone knows an open source file that has some/most/all of these functions available, that could be helpful as well.

Comment: The inclusion guards (those `#ifndef`/ `#define` / `#endif` directives around a source file) are needed only for headers, so that mutiple inclusion is prevented. You can't inlcude C files multiple times, because you don't nclude them at all. In your case, you have already signalled that the header was read by `#define`ing `mdr_stat_stuff` in `rd_stat.c`, so the header with the typedef for your struct isn't read.

Comment: Remove the inclusion guards from `rd_stat.c`.

Comment: Since you typedef'd BSTAT you don't need to write `struct` all over the place when accessing that type.

Comment: in `rd_stat.h`, the prototype `struct BSTAT init_bstat(double data[], int size);` is WRONG because there is no `struct BSTAT`, only a typedef `BSTAT`.

Comment: 1. Don't include unnecessary headers, if you are not using them. And I am not even talking about the `FPT.h`, for which you are not "positive what's in there". Your `rd_stat.h` **doesn't need a single** `#include`. 2. If you `#define mdr_stat_stuff` at the top of the `rd_stat.c` file, the entire header will be skipped then. Remove this define. 3. Already mentioned above, `BSTAT` is a typedef, `struct BSTAT` doesn't exist. So the last line in the header file has an error, and the rest of the file then won't compile at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the correct syntax of `#include "..."`. Your compiler may search in your home directory as well but `#include <...>` is for search in the system and directories added using `-I` option.
2. Remove guards from the `.c` file. It prevents your `.h` file being compiled (its content is just ignored).
3. I would suggest passing and returning pointers to the structures not the structures themselves; such a big ones will add a huge overhead on every call and return.

Comment: I made the first two changes and the program ran perfectly. Well, I also had to remove the 'struct' before the header file declaration of the function init_bstat(), but after that it ran like a charm.  Thank you very much! I don't know if I would have gotten there without help. 

As for the pointers, I actually don't know a whole lot about them. My classes were less about diving deep into the language and more about how to code maths, I took Numerical Analysis in C. Do you have any recommendations where I can learn more about pointers? Could you show me how I would use them in this case?

Comment: pointers are the essence of C language. Actually I think you just need a good book.